# Pull associated user_id from id field multiple times in query

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I'm pulling in a "manager" and his associated "employees" however I'm having some problems getting the syntax correct.

My table structure:

Managers:

```
User_ID | User_Name
1       | jay
2       | matt
3       | john
4       | Employee1
5       | Employee2
6       | Employee3
```

Employees:

```
Parent_ID | Employee_ID
1           4
1           5
1           6
```

So what you see here is I want to pull in all the employees for a particular manager.

Attempted query:

```
select managers.user_name
from managers
ifnull(group_concat(distinct(employees.employee_id) SEPARATOR ';'), 'Nobody Under You') "Employees"
left join employees on employees.employee_id=managers.id
group by managers.user_name
```

I would like for it to have:

```
jay --> Employee1; Employee2; Employee3
```

But instead it has:

```
jay --> 4;5;6
```

My problem is instead of the employee ID I want their associated user_name... can someone assist?>

Comment: Why do you have two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odd that you've got the employees in the `Managers` table but in any case, you need to join again to the same table. For example

```
SELECT
    Managers.User_Name,
    COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(emp.User_Name SEPARATOR ';'), 'Nobody Under You') AS 'Employees'
FROM Managers
LEFT JOIN Employees ON Managers.User_ID = Employees.Parent_ID
LEFT JOIN Managers emp ON Employees.Employee_ID = emp.User_ID
GROUP BY Managers.User_Name
```

SQL Fiddle ~ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/698e5d/7

Comment: @user3299633 you're welcome. I've fixed a couple of typos and provided a working example